# Find out at what time my machine got restarted and why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uptime

I have my ubuntu machine which is running Ubuntu 10.10 and that machine is running my app server.

I am suspecting that my machine got restarted today at some time but I don't know how to find out at what time my machine got restarted today? And if it got restarted then who restarted it and why it got restarted up. Is there any way I can find out these details?

I tried using `uptime` and this is what I got which means my machine is up since 20 hours and 21 minutes (am I right?)

```
david@machineA:~$ uptime
 22:55:37 up 20:21,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.05, 0.01
```

Can anyone provide me some steps how can I find out these details?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is EOL!

Comment: Yup, very well aware of that :) It's my bad luck that I got these VM's in our company which is running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Yeah it was restarted, and has been up for 20:21 hours:minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first field of `/proc/uptime` is your friend for when (go read it with `cat /proc/uptime`). It's a running count of seconds that your system has been up. The second field of that file is how many cpuseconds have been idle on your system (divide it by the number of CPUs listed in `/proc/cpuinfo` in that system to get actual seconds).

```
# if your awk is new enough, 1 second resolution.
awk '//{print strftime("%c",systime()-$1)}' /proc/uptime 
# for older awk, but requires bc binary, high resolution
date -d @$(echo $(date +%s.%N) - $(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) |bc )
# older awk, 1 second resolution, no bc
date -d @$(( $(date +%s) - $(awk '{printf "%d",$1}' /proc/uptime) ))
```

Will print the boot time of your system, within 1 second. I say within 1 second, because the is fractional, and awk only returns `systime` as an integer.

This does not tell you who or why it was restarted. The best you can do for that is the output of the `last` command, which will record normal shutdowns and reboots; as well as sessions lost as a result of a hard reboot (eg power blip, kernel bug). These aren't reliable, as they depend on nobody tampering with the `/var/log/wtmp*` files.

Here's an example of a lost session:

```
root@nms1:~# last -f /var/log/wtmp.1
root     pts/0        10.x.y.z      Mon Oct 27 05:41    gone - no logout 
root     pts/0        10.x.y.z      Mon Oct 20 04:55 - 16:47  (11:51)
```

And here's an example of a reboot.

```
[root@freepbx ~]# last
...
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-431.el6.x Mon Oct 20 13:46 - 16:13 (3+02:27)   
root     pts/2        10.x.y.z      Wed Oct 15 21:02 - 00:51 (2+03:48)   
root     pts/1        10.x.y.z      Wed Oct 15 14:17 - 00:51 (2+10:33)   
sitkasta pts/0        10.x.y.z      Tue Oct 14 20:23 - down  (5+17:22)   
root     pts/0        10.x.y.z      Tue Oct 14 10:43 - 20:22  (09:39)
```

If you want anything more, look at something like the `audit` framework, and send reboot/shutdown commands to a reliable & secure remote logging destination.

Comment: when you say first field of `/proc/uptime` you mean to say `20:21` in my case? I tried running this `awk '//{print strftime("%c",systime()-$1)}' /proc/uptime` but I got an error as `awk: line 2: function strftime never defined
awk: line 2: function systime never defined`

Comment: The awk in Ubuntu 10.10 is too old, and doesn't have those functions; I'll revise above.

Comment: Thanks `robbat` for the help. After I ran `last` command as you told me, I got one line which shows this `reboot   system boot  2.6.35-22-server Wed Nov  5 02:34 - 23:19  (20:45)` what does this mean? I was not able to understand this line `02:34 - 23:19` specifically?

Comment: `02:34 - 23:19` means that the system booted at 02:34 and shut down at `23:19`, a total of 20h45min (in my example above, it was 3 days 2 hours, 27 minutes.

Comment: meaning system rebooted at 02:34 AM in the morning today? And what does shut down mean then in this context? Isn't they should be same?

Comment: The most recent reboot entry in the `last` output is also a special case; if you run `date ; last |grep reboot` twice, at least a minute apart, you'll see that the time on the most recent entry is actually constantly being updated. 02:34AM is when the last boot started. And the second value is the current time, but only for the current boot.

Otherwise, for all previous entries, it's the startup and shutdown times of the system.

Comment: you can also use the `/var/logs/syslogs`. It tells you normally when the shutdown command was received and why it was shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below to find the machine down time.

uprecords

The time which is not show shown in the list is the reboot time.